# How to move files based on their names to specific directories in python?

Tags: python, transfer

I have a directory called `/user/local/` inside which i have several files of the form, `jenjar.dat_1` and `jenmis.dat_1`. There is another directory `/user/data` inside which there are two subdirectories of the form, `jenjar` and `jenmis`. I need a Python code that would move the `jenjar.dat_1` into the `jenjar` directory of `/user/data` and similarly, `jenmis.dat_1` into `jenmis` directory of `'/user/data`.

I guess the `os` module would work for thus but I'm confused. Most of the questions here do not show a Pythonic way to do this.

EDIT: I have found the solution to this

```
destination = '/user/local'
target = '/user/data'
destination_list = os.listdir(destination)
data_dir_list = os.listdir(target)
for fileName in destination_list:
   if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(destination, fileName)):
       for prefix in data_dir_list:
           if fileName.startswith(prefix):
               shutil.copy(os.path.join(destination, fileName), os.path.join(target, prefix, fileName))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
srcDir = '/user/local'
targetDir = '/user/data'
for fname in os.listdir(srcDir):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(srcDir, fname)):
        for prefix in ['jenjar.dat', 'jenmis.dat']:
            if fname.startswith(prefix):
                if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(targetDir, prefix)):
                    os.mkdir(os.path.join(targetDir, prefix))
                shutil.move(os.path.join(srcDir, fnmae), targetDir)
```

Comment: This code just transfers the files 'jenjar.dat_1' and 'jenmis.dat_1' to '/user/data'. The '/user/data' directory has two subdirectories 'jenmis' and 'jenjar'. I need the 'jenjar.dat_1' to go into 'jenjar' directory and 'jenmis.dat_1' to go into 'jenmis' directory.

Comment: Typo: should be `fname` not `frame` at line 4. Also the directories are `jenjar` and `jenmis` not `jenjar.dat`, so you shouldn't use `prefix` to create the dir.

Comment: There are some changes that I made to this code and I have edited my question to include the answer as well. Thank you for helping me out.