# Python: Copy files with a given extension within a folder tree into another folder tree: additional subfolder complication

Tags: python

I have a directory called /AAA inside which I have several folders called AAA_YYMMDD, inside which I have files named AAA_YYMMDD.xxx where xxx are a few different extensions. I am struggling to find and tweaking any python code that would do the following:

The destination directory is /BBB containing subfolders named AAA_YYMMDD matching the root folder BUT there is an additional subfolder called 'analysis' within each AAA_YYMMDD subfolder.

Goal: Find all files with AAA_YYMMDD.xx1 (one particular extension) within AAA root directory, then copy to a destination /BBB directory BUT it is not enough to copy files in the appropriate AAA_YYMMDD subfolders, I would like those copied files to end inside the /AAA_YYMMDD/analysis subfolder.

I found [How to move files based on their names to specific directories in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890812/how-to-move-files-based-on-their-names-to-specific-directories-in-python)
that I thought could get me there with some modifications. But I did not manage.

```
import os
import shutil

destination = r"\\xxx\yyy"
target = r"\\xxx\yyy"


destination_list = os.listdir(destination)
data_dir_list = os.listdir(target)
for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk(destination):    
   if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(destination, fnames)):
       for prefix in data_dir_list:
           if fnames.endswith(".zzz"):
               shutil.copy(os.path.join(destination, fnames), os.path.join(target, prefix, fnames))

print "done copying .zzz files"
```

(Added some borrowed code as requested)

Comment: Wanna share any code?